# QT/QML Data Model

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml, pyside

I want to create a Qt data model with a structure like below to use in Python and QML. If any values or keys are changed, added, or deleted in Python or QML I would need the values to be updated on the other side (QML or Python). This would ideally be the model used in a ListView and I would only display certain fields for the ListView. But I would use this data model to store all my information. When a test is performed for memory in Python I would want to write that test log information to this data model and display that in QML. I have read about QAbstractListModel, but I am unsure if I can make nested objects or lists and whether they would update automatically or not.

```
System: {
    Processor: {
        name: 'Processor',
        description: 'Intel i7 6600k',
        iconSource: '/resources/images/chip.svg',
        progressValue: 100,
        pageSource: '/resources/qml/Processor.qml',
        details: {
            "badge": "Intel® Core i5 processor",
            "cache": "6144 KB",
            "clock": "4200000"
        }
        testLog: [
            'Starting Cpu Test',
            'Detected Intel CPU',
            'Performing intense calculations',
            'Processing calculations still',
            'Cleaning up',
            'Test Passed'
        ]
    }    
    Memory: {
        name: 'Memory',
        description: 'Kingston 16GB DDR3',
        iconSource: '/resources/images/ram.svg',
        progressValue: 50,
        pageSource: '/resources/qml/Processor.qml',
        details: {
            "device_locator_string": "ChannelB-DIMM1",
            "device_set": 0,
            "error_handle": 65534,
            "extended_size": 0,
            "form_factor": "Unknown"
        },
        testLog: [
            'Starting Memory Test',
            'Detected 2 x RAM modules',
            'Performing intense calculations',
            'Processing calculations still',
            'Cleaning up',
            'Test Failed'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: QAbstractItemModel is suited for tree-like structures. You need to implement the `parent` function (at least in C++, not sure about Python, but should give you an idea)

Comment: @Amfasis do you know if I can feed a QAbstractItemModel into a ListView? Isn't it only QAbstractListModel and QAbstractTableModel that works with a ListView?

Comment: no you can definitely feed any descendant from QAbstractItemModel to most of the model properties in Qt components (ListView, GridView, Repeater etc) see [doc for C++](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options in this case such as:

- Create a model based on QAbstractItemModel where you provide the properties through roles.
- Create a QObject Device that has the desired properties as qproperties and expose it through a qproperty associated with a signal from another QObject, the QObject Device list and use that list as a model.
- Create a model as a QAbstractListModel (or QStandardItemModel) and expose the QObject through a role.
- Create a QObject that exposes a list of QObjects Device through ListProperty.

In this case I have chosen the first option for a demo:

**main.py**

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import sys
from typing import Callable

from PySide2.QtCore import (
    Property,
    QCoreApplication,
    QObject,
    QVariantAnimation,
    Qt,
    QUrl,
)
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


@dataclass
class item_property:
    role: int
    function: Callable = None

    def __call__(self, function):
        self.function = function
        return self


class item_property_impl(property):
    def __init__(self, role, function):
        super().__init__()
        self._role = role
        self._function = function

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if hasattr(obj, "_initial"):
            obj.setData(self._function(obj), self._role)
            delattr(obj, "_initial")
        return obj.data(self._role)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        obj.setData(value, self._role)


class ItemMeta(type(QStandardItem), type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        for key in attrs.keys():
            attr = attrs[key]
            if not isinstance(attr, item_property):
                continue
            new_prop = item_property_impl(attr.role, attr.function)
            attrs[key] = new_prop
            if not hasattr(cls, "attrs"):
                cls._names = []
            cls._names.append(key)

        obj = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        return obj

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        obj = super().__call__(*args, **kw)
        obj._initial = True
        for key in cls._names:
            getattr(obj, key)
        return obj


class Item(QStandardItem, metaclass=ItemMeta):
    pass


keys = (b"name", b"description", b"icon", b"progress", b"source", b"details", b"log")
ROLES = (
    NAME_ROLE,
    DESCRIPTION_ROLE,
    ICON_ROLE,
    PROGRESS_ROLE,
    SOURCE_ROLE,
    DETAILS_ROLE,
    LOG_ROLE,
) = [Qt.UserRole + i for i, _ in enumerate(keys)]


class Device(Item):
    @item_property(role=NAME_ROLE)
    def name(self):
        return ""

    @item_property(role=DESCRIPTION_ROLE)
    def description(self):
        return ""

    @item_property(role=ICON_ROLE)
    def icon(self):
        return ""

    @item_property(role=PROGRESS_ROLE)
    def progress(self):
        return 0

    @item_property(role=SOURCE_ROLE)
    def source(self):
        return ""

    @item_property(role=DETAILS_ROLE)
    def details(self):
        return dict()

    @item_property(role=LOG_ROLE)
    def log(self):
        return list()


class DeviceManager(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._model = QStandardItemModel()
        self._model.setItemRoleNames(dict(zip(ROLES, keys)))

    def get_model(self):
        return self._model

    model = Property(QObject, fget=get_model, constant=True)

    def add_device(self, *, name, description, icon, progress, source, details, log):
        dev = Device()
        dev.name = name
        dev.description = description
        dev.icon = icon
        dev.progress = progress
        dev.source = source
        dev.details = details
        dev.log = log
        self.model.appendRow(dev)
        return dev


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    manager = DeviceManager()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("device_manager", manager)

    url = QUrl("main.qml")

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(handle_object_created, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    engine.load(url)

    processor = manager.add_device(
        name="Processor",
        description="Intel i7 6600k",
        icon="/resources/images/chip.svg",
        progress=10,
        source="resources/qml/Processor.qml",
        details={
            "badge": "Intel® Core i5 processor",
            "cache": "6144 KB",
            "clock": "4200000",
        },
        log=[
            "Starting Cpu Test",
            "Detected Intel CPU",
            "Performing intense calculations",
            "Processing calculations still",
            "Cleaning up",
            "Test Passed",
        ],
    )

    memory = manager.add_device(
        name="Memory",
        description="Kingston 16GB DDR3",
        icon="/resources/images/ram.svg",
        progress=50,
        source="resources/qml/Memory.qml",
        details={
            "device_locator_string": "ChannelB-DIMM1",
            "device_set": 0,
            "error_handle": 65534,
            "extended_size": 0,
            "form_factor": "Unknown",
        },
        log=[
            "Starting Memory Test",
            "Detected 2 x RAM modules",
            "Performing intense calculations",
            "Processing calculations still",
            "Cleaning up",
            "Test Failed",
        ],
    )

    def update_progress(value):
        processor.progress = value

    animation = QVariantAnimation(
        startValue=processor.progress, endValue=100, duration=3 * 1000
    )
    animation.valueChanged.connect(update_progress)
    animation.start()

    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    ListView {
        id: view

        property url currentSource: ""

        model: device_manager.model
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: parent.height
        spacing: 10
        clip: true
        flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
        currentIndex: -1

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
        }

        highlight: Rectangle {
            color: "lightsteelblue"
            radius: 5
        }

        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: rect

            color: "transparent"
            border.color: ListView.isCurrentItem ? "red" : "green"
            height: column.height
            width: ListView.view.width

            Column {
                id: column

                Text {
                    text: model.name
                }

                ProgressBar {
                    from: 0
                    to: 100
                    value: model.progress
                }

                Label {
                    text: "Log:"
                    font.bold: true
                    font.pointSize: 15
                }

                Text {
                    text: model.log.join("\n")
                }

            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    rect.ListView.view.currentIndex = index;
                    rect.ListView.view.currentSource = model.source;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    Rectangle {
        x: view.width
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: parent.height
        color: "salmon"

        Loader {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            source: view.currentSource
        }

    }

}
```

Processor.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Rectangle{
    color: "red"
    width: 100
    height: 40
    Text{
        text: "Processor"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Memory.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Rectangle{
    color: "blue"
    width: 100
    height: 40
    Text{
        text: "Memory"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

```
├── main.py
├── main.qml
└── resources
    └── qml
        ├── Memory.qml
        └── Processor.qml
```

[image]

Comment: The first option you mentioned was using QAbstractItemModel and you said you were making a demo of that? But I think your demo doesn't use QAbstractItemModel.

Comment: @Aaron QAbstractItemModel is the base of many models and among them QStandardItemModel, the advantage of QStandardItemModel is that it already implements many functionalities saving me time in programming. You can implement the model from scratch but I was lazy.

Comment: This is incredible and super helpful! I am going to study this over the next few days and read up the documentation as well. I'll ask any of my questions here, thank you soo much again Edwin!

Comment: I have been studying your answer. How would I make this work? memory.details['form_factor'] = 'DDR3' or memory.log.append('new log entry'). 
I know I can assign it to a variable and write the whole object. But how could I modify the code to be able to manipulate objects like this directly in Python?

Comment: Also when you declare the model property in device_manager why do you use constant=True instead of notify? I thought "constant" is only used if the property is immutable.

Comment: @Aaron 1) My code is only a demo, I do not try to cover all the optimizations or behaviors that you expect, if you want more functionalities then you will have to implement them yourself. 2) The model is constant because the model object does not change, another thing is the information that it handles that if it changes and for that the model has its own signals that QML knows.

Comment: Ok thanks, could you explain to me what the dataclass item_property is doing?

Comment: @Aaron they are an easy way to associate python properties to model roles.

Comment: Edwin please see my update to my question. Could you please  help with that?

Comment: @Aaron If you have another question then create another post for that reversed your update. You cannot change the requirements at all times since with this you could never have an answer as accepted, put yourself in the case of a user who wants the community to do its work and every time his boss asks him for a new requirement he publishes it here. If you want I can implement that logic but it will be a job (and obviously it will have a cost), if you are interested write me an email.